# Placeholders in the Postgres query for generate_series returns unknown

Tags: postgresql, go, generate-series

I try to make a query with placeholders like this

```
database.Query("select login,displayname from (select distinct $1+trunc(random()*$2)::integer as id from generate_series($3,$4) g ) r join users using(id) limit 10",min_id,max_id-min_id,min_id,max_id)
```

It throws me an error:

```
pq: function generate_series(unknown, unknown) is not unique
```

Then I find a solution to format query as a string

```
query:=fmt.Sprintf("select login,displayname from (select distinct %v+trunc(random()*%v)::integer as id from generate_series(%v,%v) g ) r join users using(id) limit 10",min_id,max_id-min_id,min_id,max_id)
```

and it works.

I'd like to make it work in a right way, but I don't understand why it doesn't.

Updated:

```
var min_id int64
var max_id int64
err:=_database.QueryRow("select min(id),max(id) from users").Scan(&min_id, &max_id)
if err!=nil { 
    log.Panicf("Failed to get min and max %v",err.Error())
    return
}

var rows *sql.Rows

query:=fmt.Sprintf("select login,displayname from (select distinct %v+trunc(random()*%v)::integer as id from generate_series(%v,%v) g ) r join users using(id) limit 10",min_id,max_id-min_id,min_id,max_id)
log.Printf(query)
rows,err=_database.Query("select login,displayname from (select distinct $1+trunc(random()*$2)::integer as id from generate_series($3,$4) g ) r join users using(id) limit 10",min_id,max_id-min_id,min_id,max_id)
if err!=nil {
    log.Panicf("failed to get random entries: %v",err)
}
```

Comment: What are the types of max_id and min_id?

Comment: they are integers and they are valid

Comment: there are many integer types in Go: int, uint, int64, etc. My wild guess is that postgresql driver doesn't support all of them. Try using int64.

Comment: didn't help. I'll update initial post with a more code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try breaking your query apart. You'll see the first part works fine:

```
db.QueryRow("SELECT $1+trunc(random()*$2) as test", 10, 5)
```

This probably works because `$1` and `$2` are used with mathematical operators (and/or because `trunc()` and `random()` both return numbers), so postgres can infer the data type.

So it looks like it's the `generate_series()` parameters that aren't being properly determined. Postgres *can* infer data types based on parameters, e.g.

```
if err := db.QueryRow("SELECT trunc($1,2) as test", 1.4343).Scan(&output); err != nil {panic(err)}
// output = 1.43
```

*However*, if it's a polymorphic function ambiguity can arise and it will fail, e.g.

```
if err := db.QueryRow("SELECT trunc($1) as test", 1.4343).Scan(&output); err != nil {panic(err)}
// panic: pq: function trunc(unknown) is not unique
```

To avoid ambiguity, explicitly cast parameters in your prepared statement, like: `generate_series($3::int,$4::int)`

Comment: @ekiyanov no problem!